# Services Error message 1067 for SQL Service Name :- MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server-2012

**SQL-server** When i start SQL server service from services, it shows an error message 1067 the process terminated unexpectedly

Comment: maybe Registry Error  , also sql server configuration manager doesn't show all services lot of them are missing i only have integration services and , sql server browser

Comment: Have you moved the master database files?

Comment: i've deleted them wile reinstalling sql server and it's deleted now

Comment: The services are not going to start if you have deleted the system database files.

Comment: what should i do :D

Comment: Do you have any user databases that has data you need? If so, do you have backups?

Comment: i have databases that I've created only , is this because i installed dreamweaver ? , then i had this problem and i reinstalled sql server .. :D